# What is the Emacs equivalent to Vim command z-<enter> (put current line on top)

Tags: vim, emacs, ide

In Vim there is a command to place the line where the cursor is on the top of the window... that is:

<kbd>z</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

I know there is an equivalent but <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> (L) did not do it, it did what <kbd>z</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> does on vim. 
Anybody?

**EDIT: *Specifying OS and versions***

I'm running GNU Emacs 22.1.1 in OS X 10.9.3 and already tried <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> repeatedly without luck.

Comment: I removed the old emacs and then did a `brew install emacs`. Note that your default emacs would come first in the path so brew's emacs would not get loaded if you haven't followed the `brew doctor` recommendations...  `/usr/bin/emacs` vs `/usr/local/bin/emacs`. For that reason make sure you remove it or change the path... `which emacs`. Thanks to @sds for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Recent Emacs

Since [2007-11-16](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/revision/82082) ([Emacs 22.2](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu-emacs/2008-03/msg00000.html)), you need to hit [<kbd>C-l</kbd>](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recentering.html) *several times* because it *cycles* between different positionings:

> C-l runs the command recenter-top-bottom (found in global-map), which
>   is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `window.el'.
>
> It is bound to C-l.
>
> (recenter-top-bottom &optional ARG)
>
> Move current buffer line to the specified window line. With no prefix
>   argument, successive calls place point according to the cycling order
>   defined by `recenter-positions'.
>
> A prefix argument is handled like `recenter':  With numeric prefix
>   ARG, move current line to window-line ARG.  With plain`C-u', move
>   current line to window center.

## Older Emacs

Are you sure you want to keep using an 6+ year old release?

Comment: I'm running GNU Emacs 22.1.1 in OS X 10.9.3 C-l is just putting the current line on the middle... Any ideas?

Comment: This feature has been available for **6** years since 22.2. Please upgrade (use, e.g., [http://brew.sh/])

Comment: Ohh, I'm ashamed! Will do.

Comment: It is apple who should be ashamed of shipping an ancient version of a major tool.

Answer (score 2):

In [evil-mode](http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Evil), which combines the best of both worlds, you can also use z-Enter (or z-t).